# ASP.NET 5 vNext. Publishing a "dist" sub folder only

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

I am developing an **ASP.NET** vnext web project in **VS 2015 RC** and deploying to **Azure**.
I created a sub folder called `dist` inside the `wwwroot` folder and want it to be published to Azure. The dist folder contains all the js, html, and css but all optimized and minified versions.

I used this command:

```
dnu publish --out "C:\temp" --configuration Release --wwwroot "wwwroot/dist" --wwwroot-out "wwwroot" --no-source
```

taken from here [ASPNET Home Github Page](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-utility#publish-dnu-publish)

After I submitted the command, I got a folder with a couple of cmd files and two folders: `approot` and `wwwroot`. 
I then used FTP to transfer these two folders into Azure and replace the old ones, but now the app doesn't run.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Why are you trying to publish only a dist subfolder of wwwroot?  You should not be putting any js source code in wwwroot.  You should have a script or something other location outside of wwwroot and then use task runners to copy/minify/etc your scripts plus any libraries.  wwwroot should reflect what you want the severable portion of your application to look like.

Answer (score 2):

Used this command and it worked..

```
dnu publish --out "F:\publish" --configuration Release --wwwroot "wwwroot/dist" --wwwroot-out "wwwroot" --runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta4
```

Still i want a web deploy option to allow me to publish a sub wwwroot folder as same as I can from the command line or ftp. Maybe an option exists that i dont know about.

Comment: I tried deploying beta4 to Azure, but I don't think Azure had support for it right now. You can take the the contents of `F:\publish` and FTP them to the `site` directory on an Azure Website. For now I am using Kestrel to run the website on my Ubuntu build machine.